# Have Parsoid service and visual editor installed, nothing happens after edit button

Tags: php, mediawiki, visual-editor

My MediaWiki version is 1.22, and have Parsoid service and visual editor extension already installed and enabled in my Localsettings.php file.

I think Parsoid service has no problem because url [_wikitext](http://uhaan.com:8000/_wikitext/) is available.

But in my wiki page, the edit button have no response, just submitted parameter '`&veaction=edit`' and nothing happens.

And yes, I do have javascript errors when click on edit button.

Error 1: "Uncaught Error: Unknown dependency: mediawiki.cookie"
Error 2: "Uncaught ReferenceError: importScript is not defined"

But I'm not quite familiar with front end and javascript, also don't know how to develop extention for mediawiki, so just don't know what to do next.

What can I do to solve this?
My system version is Centos6.5 , Parsoid and visual editor version are all 1.22

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does your browsers JavaScript console print out to you? I assume there is a JavaScript error.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It does have a javascript error but not relevant to visual editor I think. It says:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: importScript is not defined"

Comment: @Florian                           Yes, it has. There are two, but i don't know how to solve it. I've edited the question. Could you give me some guidence? Thanks very much

Comment: Do you really has MediaWiki 1.22 installed and all files up to date? Make sure, that you use extensikns (and versions) that are compatible with Mediawiki 1.22. In your case I would assume, that there is some mismatch (e.g. a newer extension version). Is your wiki public? Could you post the url?

Comment: @Florian Yes, maybe. Because we need to change the look of default  mediawiki , we added a lot css in the common.css file and some php files like vector.php  .     And we really need to change those appearances because our layout is much special. This is the wiki i working on [uhaan](http://uhaan.com). Do i have any way to get over those javascript errors?   Or, Any idea make visual editor compatible with our site?       Thanks very much.

Comment: @Florian     And our wiki is better viewed in chrome, IE still have some frontend to fix.

Comment: Is the wiki really supposed to have the entire layout rotated by 90°? http://web.archive.org/web/20160207073451/http://wiki.uhaan.com/index.php?title=%E1%A0%A8%E1%A0%A2%E1%A0%AD%E1%A0%A4%E1%A0%B7_%E1%A0%AC%E1%A0%A0%E1%A0%AD%E1%A0%A4%E1%A0%B3%E1%A0%A0%E1%A0%B0%E1%A0%A4

Answer (score 0):

This recalls me of a similar case in the past where someone copied some JavaScript code which required `importScript` to be defined, but forgot to copy said function, and broke all the JavaScript in the wiki.

I don't see anything in [your MediaWiki:Common.js](http://web.archive.org/web/20160214125850/http://wiki.uhaan.com/index.php?title=%E1%A0%AE%E1%A0%B8%E1%A0%B3%E1%A0%A2%E1%A0%B6%E1%A0%A0_%E1%A0%B8%E1%A0%A2%E1%A0%BA%E1%A0%A2:Common.js), so it seems you literally hacked the MediaWiki *files*. This is highly discouraged: please move all your custom code from the files to the [on-wiki JavaScript definitions and self-contained gadgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript#List_of_JavaScript_pages). By doing one piece at a time, you'll also see what is broken.

Meanwhile, I'm unable to do any testing on your wiki because its network is horrible from Europe: 400+ ms latency, 50 % packet loss. Packets get lost somewhere in China. Is networking better for you? If not, I doubt that you can manage to load JavaScript properly with such a connection.

```
mtr -w -c 250 wiki.uhaan.com
 11.|-- 62-101-124-98.fastres.net                   0.8%   250   46.1  54.2   3.3 151.1  37.2
 12.|-- 89.96.200.114                               0.0%   250   47.2  69.2   2.7 151.6  33.3
 13.|-- mno-b2-link.telia.net                       0.0%   250   54.0  64.1   3.3 120.3  30.0
 14.|-- ffm-bb2-link.telia.net                      0.8%   250   50.3  86.2  18.5 221.7  39.8
 15.|-- ffm-b10-link.telia.net                      2.4%   250   44.5  69.2  18.3 136.5  32.4
 16.|-- chinatelecom-ic-306387-ffm-b10.c.telia.net  0.0%   250   36.4  61.5  18.9 133.3  30.2
 17.|-- 202.97.58.61                               94.8%   250  372.3 351.9 312.9 440.4  38.9
 18.|-- 202.97.33.133                              40.4%   250  309.7 329.1 300.3 397.6  24.7
 19.|-- 202.97.50.233                              44.0%   250  325.9 333.9 307.0 410.6  23.4
 20.|-- ???                                        100.0   250    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 21.|-- 61.164.31.182                              80.4%   250  317.6 345.2 314.7 425.4  30.4
 22.|-- ???                                        100.0   249    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 23.|-- 42.120.244.198                             47.8%   249  405.8 422.7 375.4 502.2  35.2
 24.|-- 42.120.244.210                             47.4%   247  443.1 480.4 402.6 561.9  35.7
 25.|-- ???                                        100.0   246    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 26.|-- 115.29.170.20                              53.3%   246  418.8 413.0 343.3 498.9  34.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Nemo. I will try as you said. Best wishes for you!